# How to use mic on simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I've already add privacy to Info.plist but I can't use mic on simulator. Does anyone have an answer?
Thank you!
Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does work now. You can specify hardware input/output under the Simulator Menu: Hardware > Audio Input / Audio Output.

https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/deve63797392

edit: verified on my simulator that this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. From [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html):

> Though most of the functionality of devices can be simulated in Simulator, some hardware features must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that are not simulated as of iOS 8.2 are:
>
> Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope) are unsupported.
>
> Audio and video input (camera and microphone) are unsupported.
>
> Proximity sensor
>
> Barometer
>
> Ambient light sensor

Comment: So there's no way to use mic on stimulator. Right?

Comment: That is how I understand the documentation also.

Comment: Is this still not possible? I can install a tap in my input in AVAudioEngine and receive samples, but they are all 0 in the simulator. It works in real hardware with the same code, but not in the simulator. Is this generally not possible? Then, why does the simulator offer options regarding the sound input?

Comment: On XCode 12, I attached an external microphone and changed Simulator -> i/o -> audio input to the new device and it works fine. Just the built in microphone is not available to simulator.